# SP2007 formula to remove every occurrence of '#;' from a field

Tags: calculated-column

I want to create a calculated column to have values without the '#;' in it.  What is the formula to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to replace it once, you can use this formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("#;",[MyColumn])),REPLACE([MyColumn],FIND("#;",[MyColumn]),2,""),[MyColumn])
```

Answer (score -1):

there are lots of formulas here... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx
hopefully you can find the one you're looking for there.

Comment: That's a good source for formulas.  Need to find a nice fit.  Thanks.